# Fetching images from server while drawing the cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Why should we avoid loading a image from server while drawing a cell?

In my app I get data from server which contains image URLs as well. Now, I draw my cells and use these image URLs to fetch image from the server and draw it. Now, sometimes image does not get displayed even if image is actually present at that URL as I can see it through browser.

Is there any cell drawing limitation which could cause this issue? Shall I fetch images when I get data from server.

Does cell rendering happens before image is actually drawn.

Comment: It sounds like the image isn't always completing the download before the cell is being drawn. You'd be better of getting the images as soon as you get the URL back.

Comment: I download the image in a thread.

Comment: after the thread completes download for a specific image, you need to update the cell. Use [table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths... For this to work you need to have some kind of mapping that describes which image url is drawn in which cell.

Comment: That mapping is there and I reload the cells as well. Issue here is that, sometimes, I get request timed out error while fetching the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *imgUrl = [ImageURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if(imgUrl != nil)
{
    NSString * ImagePath;

    NetworkManager *manager = [[NetworkManager alloc] init];

    ImagePath = [manager GetFile:imgUrl];

    [manager release];

    manager = nil;

    if(ImagePath != nil)

    {

          UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:ImagePath]];        

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(50, 50));

        // now redraw our image in a smaller rectangle.
        [newImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(25, 10, 30, 30)];

        newImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        cell.imageView.image  = newImage; 
    }
}
  return cell;
```

}

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

What could be happening is you have a main thread which is the UI display thread. By fetching image from a url from this thread, you are essentially blocking the cell (i.e. scrolling). Also might be the case that the image is in the process of downloading in which case you'll not see it till it downloads.

Generally `UITableView` does not display the cell till it's ready to be displayed, by doing the image download in the main thread you are harming your performance. What you should do is to launch a background thread which downloads the image from the url & then update the cell of the image contents when the download is ready.

Best way is to have an initial placeholder like a default image or a spinner, which gets replaced when the main image download gets done.

Dont worry you dont need to implement all this. No point in reinventing the wheel. Here's an awesome library which I use for the same - [**UIImageView + WebCache**](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the image download is taking more time. You should be using placeholder images until the download completes. You can't stop the user from scrolling.

Comment: I have a spinner there and once there is no image returned from server I show a placeholder image. I want to know if this is a wrong way of doing this.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Another approach is keeping the placeholder image from the beginning (doing away with the spinner) & replacing the placeholder with the downloaded image when the download finishes. Perhaps results in less UI noise.

Answer (score 0):

fetch images when I you data from server and pass the information to the view.
like

```
ImageView *imageView = [[ImageView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
imageView.prod=self.prod;
imageView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:imageView animated:YES];
[imageView release];
imageView=nil;
```

hope this will solve your problem